# what does <promiseResponse>.json() do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

in the following code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(options.url)
      .then((response) => response.json()
      .then((r) => setData(r)));
  }, [options.url]);
```

what does **response.json()** do ? why do we need to do a .json(), would it be fine if one did not invoke that function?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json

Comment: One of several methods for preprocessing response, and yes, if it's a JSON, then response.json() is mandatory before parsing the actual contents. Here's the full reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Comment: @mbojko `before parsing the actual contents` to be accurate, .json does the parse, so your comment isn't quite accurate

Answer (score 1):

`response.json()` reads the `Response`'s `body` as a `ReadableStream`, parses it as JSON, and returns the parsed data in an asynchronous `Promise`.

Without doing this, you'd have the `Response` object, but you wouldn't be able to access the data inside it right away.